Dynamic Database Model / Entity in Spring Boot
I have a very very big database (around 20 million rows in total) that will grow as the application is still being used and none of those inserted rows will be deleted. By the current trend, it would be 30 million rows by next 3 years.
As for splitting the rows, I think about splitting current table into 10 tables.
TABLE_DATA -> TABLE_DATA_00, TABLE_DATA_01, ..., TABLE_DATA_09

These tables has the very same structure. I would like to have this dynamic class that able to smartly pick on which table to get the data:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity("TABLE_DATA_XX")
public class Data {
   String id;
   String name;
   String image;
}

So by this one class, it can work for the 10 tables. Is this possible?

I think you should consider table partitioning as a solution. Table partitioning enables you to segment a table into partitions based on key(s), effectively allowing you to work with a single table. Simply choose a key for partitioning, such as the insertion date in the table, to store the data on a daily basis within the table. Partitioning tables can significantly impact data processing speed and offers many benefits.
this link should be useful.
